# HTML helper for EnumList don't have the same style as rest of the form

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm doing an application in ASP.NET MVC and I'm using an Enum with different countries for a drop down list. The list is working, but it's just looking like a unstyled list compared to the other input fields with the Bootstrap style. What could be wrong?

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Country, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Country, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })*@

            @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.Country, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Country, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: How does it look anyway try this, its the same.A screenshot would help. @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.Country, new { @class="form-control"})

Comment: @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.Country, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })

Comment: @HastaPasta Thanks for your comment! I just found the same solution in a tutorial and it works. Why is this working better?

Comment: htmlAttributes are fairly new. Honestly I have not used it. I am still using vs 2012. Bit conservative in adopting newer technologies as they are not yet refined. Check in your dev tools what it generates, I am pretty sure it add's some extra class to your dropdown. Thanks

Comment: Apparently the helper signature/overload  is EnumDropDownListFor(HtmlHelper, Expression>)

Comment: @HastaPasta Thanks for the help!

Comment: Chris explains the use of htmlAttributes http://cpratt.co/html-editorfor-and-htmlattributes/

Comment: @HastaPasta Great link! I will read that! Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are wrapping the `htmlAttribues` parameter and it's value again inside an anonymous object. Just remove it and it should work.

Change

```
 @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.Country, 
                             new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

to

```
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.Country,
                                        htmlAttributes : new { @class = "form-control" })
```

or simply,

```
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.Country, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: It also worked when I used this: @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.Country, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })

Comment: Yes. It will. but in your question , you had an extra `new {` in-front of that.

Comment: I found the first alternatives in a tutorial and thought it should work. There must be a reason for this extra new? It's works perfect without the extra new, but it's strange. Any explanation why?

Comment: I guess it is a typo ! Actually If you use that and check your page source (View source), you will understand how it is being used.

Comment: @front-back, what you read in a tutorial must have been used in an `EditorFor`, not an `EnumDropDownListFor`.